# Assiging a 'User Stamp' when saving a record

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

So the first thing is that every table has 4 fields. `Created_By`, `Created_Date`, `Last_Updated_By` and `Last_Updated_Date`. This will allow me to keep a track of who saved what records and when. I want a public sub (or function?) to update these fields when any record is saved.

Ideally I don't want to have to copy/call my code from every form, but I will if that's what is necessary. I imagine there is a way of doing this globally.

I currently have the following:

```vb
Public gLoggedIn As Integer
Public Function get_global(Global_name As String) As Variant 
 Select Case Global_name
        Case "Employee_ID"
            get_global = gLoggedIn
End Select
End Function
```

My next thing is to add vba code to fill the 2 of the 4 fields. The following is something I have in one of my forms, but like I say, I want to able to achieve this globally on every save.

```vb
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If Me.NewRecord = True Then
    Me.[Created_By] = gLoggedIn
    Me.[Created_Date] = Now()
Else
    Me.[Last_Updated_By] = gLoggedIn
    Me.[Last_Updated_Date] = Now()
End If
End Sub
```

How can I do this globally?

I'm not sure if 'me' is the correct reference to us if this is global?

Comment: Access 2010 has triggers alias macros. That would be the ideal place to do it

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean? I would also prefer to use VBA over macros.

Comment: With VBA you will have to code separately for each form

Comment: what is 'triggers alias macros' and how is it used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly for your demand, you could use a VBA modul with following sub

```
Public Sub setTimestamp(objForm As Form)
    If objForm.NewRecord = True Then
        objForm![Created_By] = gLoggedIn
        objForm![Created_Date] = DateTime.Now
    Else
        objForm![Last_Updated_By] = gLoggedIn
        objForm![Last_Updated_Date] = DateTime.Now
    End If
End sub
```

You need to call this method in every form when the Timestamp Update should be fired (BTW: I would recommend an event when a save button is clicked or field update, because an edit in the dataset of the form at form update event will probably cause another form update event and could lead to an endless loop).

```
call setTimestamp(Me)
```

But you should alternatively consider using a macro like @E Mett said in comment.

Another hint: If you set the variable `gLoggedIn` to public, you can refer directly without using a function. (You did this even in your example) A function makes sense when you want to hide the variable inside a modul as private. This is called *encapsulation*, if you want to learn more about it.

**EDIT** 
Changed code by andre451  ' s suggestion.

Comment: If called in the `BeforeUpdate` event, it won't create problems. -- The code gets a bit cleaner if you use the Form itself as parameter, not the form name. `Call setTimestamp(Me)`

Comment: Yes @Andre451, I agree passing the form would be the perfect solution like I would do in OO-Systems. But I could not try it when I posted the answer. I did not know the forms-object type name. Maybe I update the answer later.

Comment: `Public Sub setTimestamp(objForm As Form)` or `Public Sub setTimestamp(objForm As Access.Form)`. Both work, use the one that is better readable for you.

Comment: Does this result in any problems with control focus? I am wondering, if the user has updated a textbox, for example, and the above VBA tries to update other fields, does it cause problems? If so, the value may need to be stored in a variable until Form_Unload.